# Trying to default a legend value as hidden using logi info

Tags: highcharts

When I select a legend item my input is hidden from a highcharts-container class with id = highcharts-2:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Chart1_legend" name="Chart1_legend" value="[{&quot;value&quot;:true,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}]">
```

Anyway to default in this attribute?  Was trying this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(#Chart1).highcharts().series[1].update({
    showInLegend: false
  });
})
```

Chart with all elements shown:

[All elements shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOMmJ.png)

Chart with the first element hidden:

[First element hidden after legend selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wByas.png)

[image: Include script to log two console entries of Highcharts.charts]

[image: Two console logs up top from script and manual concole entry of Highcharts.charts1 appended on bottom]

Comment: Can you added the screenshot of what is the output page for better reference and understand of the expected outcome?

Comment: Hi @CSLogiFloat01, Please describe your problem more precisely. Some live example would be very useful.

Comment: Thank you both @SinhNguyen for the reply.  I've edited my post with a before and after image of the series bar chart.  The second image is after selecting element 1 in the legen.  My goal is to have the chart display with element 1 defaulting as hidden.  Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide!

Comment: Thank you both @ppotaczek for the reply. I've edited my post with a before and after image of the series bar chart. The second image is after selecting element 1 in the legen. My goal is to have the chart display with element 1 defaulting as hidden. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the `visible` property in the first series object:

```
    series: [{
        visible: false,
        ...
    }, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w10a8tos/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.visible

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, thats definitely what i'm trying to achieve.  Would you possibly be able to reference how to do that at runtime?  I keep receiving an error that my chart is undefined when passing in Highcharts.charts[1].series[1].  If I log that in the console after everything has rendered, I see the series I want to alter as i would expect.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Just want to add two screenshot to describe my last comment better.  I'm logging to entries to the console.  Highcharts.charts returns my array of charts and index 1 is an array, but Highcharts.charts[1] returns undefined.  When I log Highcharts.charts[1] manually into the console, that chart array is returned as expected.  I have added the two screenshot to the main post.  Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: You can store a chart in a variable and use the `hide` method, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0hsLwnvk/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek,  Your example definitely helped me figure out the problem.  It was a timing issue of when I was trying to grab the chart from the index before the index was being created.  Setting a timeout like you did in your example allowed this to work for me!

Comment: I have used `setTimeout` only to mock async behaviour, the chart should be available synchronously.